# El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'Proyecto' no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy intentando unir dos proyectos mediante referencias, me permite incluirlo, invocar a las clases del proyecto y compila sin excepciones, pero a la hora de depurar me salta una ventana de error de depuración y en consola me dice:

> El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'Proyecto' no se encontró (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

El código de ambos proyectos está bien y me llama la atención que no me notifique que la referencia no es correcta hasta que depuro, en ese momento se pone con un triangulo amarillo, como si estuviera *missing* pero si puedo invocar a sus funciones.

¿Qué es lo que sucede? ¿Es un bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no se encuentra en el código y por ello lo hace bien, el problema viene al depurar por dos motivos:

1. La arquitectura de los proyectos es diferente.
   Puedes tener un proyecto en x86 y otro en x64 por ello no son compatibles y solo es visible en depuración, puedes verlo en las propiedades del proyecto

> click derecho en el proyecto > Propiedades > Compilación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2. Tienen frameworks diferentes. Si están en frameworks diferentes pueden no tener compatibilidad entre ellos, teniendo la misma problemática y no permitiéndote depurar, puedes verlo también en:

> click derecho en el proyecto > Propiedades > Aplicación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]